# Google Cloud Messaging displays special characters wrong

Tags: java, character-encoding, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

I have a Google Cloud Function (GCF) that sends a Push Notification via Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). The title and body of the notification contain special characters (ä, ö, ü). The problem is that the notification fails to display these special characters correctly on the smartphone. Instead, it shows '??'. My first guess was that the charset of the JVM of the GCF was wrong but I checked that with `Charset.defaultCharset()` and `System.getProperty("file.enconding")`. Both return UTF-8. But nevertheless, even log messages are showing '??' instead of the special characters. Is the GCF environment using another charset that the default one?

Anybody has an idea how to find that out? Or how to solve it?

EDIT: Running the function locally on my machine has no problems displaying special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set the build environment variables as flag with the deploy command:

```sh
$ gcloud functions deploy my-function ... --set-build-env-vars=JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

I still don't understand why this is necessary if the default charset is also UTF-8 without that command flag.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  source encoding in pom.xml properties resolves the issue.

```
 <properties>
   <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
   <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

 </properties>
```