# Google Cloud function can't display non-ascii character

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, character-encoding

Have a encoding problem for java cloud function in GCP, non ascii character can not be displayed, e.g.

```
public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) throws Exception {
String text = "最近一篇来自 Blogto 的文章指出“;
logger.info(text) ;
}
```

Will give me ??????Blogto?????

I don't have this problem in local. Options tried but neither works
Please advise. Thank you!

1. Add below to maven properties
   `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`
2. Add env variable to `gcloud functions deploy` as described: [Google Cloud Messaging displays special characters wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70824529/google-cloud-messaging-displays-special-characters-wron..).
   `--set-build-env-vars=JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`
3. Add system variable to mvn build before gcloud deploy.
   Refernece: https://www.cloudhadoop.com/maven-character-encoding/
   `mvn -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8  ....`